# TensorFlow - Specific digit recognition in an image (SVHN like)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, text-recognition

I am trying to build a classifier using TensorFlow to recognize a specific part of a text in a neural net. I was inspired by the SVHN project to recognize the clock in soccer pictures. During the entire project, I am only focused on the clock only. I add a picture to be more explicit about my project.

The first thing that I did was to crop the pictures around the clock and predict the digits (it could be 3 or 4 digits 9:38 or 11:34 for instance). It worked well, I have a good accuracy (>90% on test set) with 20k pictures for my training set.

Now I would like to do something more complicated and I think a neural net should be able to do it but I am not sure. So I don't crop exactly the clock but I crop the whole scoreboard (with team names, etc) and I still want to predict the clock.
I tried with 20k pictures and 40k pictures for my training. In both cases, I only have 70% of accuracy on the test set. The clock is approximately always at the same position in the pictures (at the top of the scoreboard).

[image: Explanations]

I don't understand why the accuracy is so low. If someone has a clue, it would be really helpful. Thank you very much for any help.

**Specifications:**

**image size :** 32x32
**numbers of labels :** 11 (0-9 + blank)
**model :**
7-layer CNN.
C1: convolutional layer, batch_size x 28 x 28 x 16, convolution size: 5 x 5 x 1 x 16
S2: sub-sampling layer, batch_size x 14 x 14 x 16
C3: convolutional layer, batch_size x 10 x 10 x 32, convolution size: 5 x 5 x 16 x 32
S4: sub-sampling layer, batch_size x 5 x 5 x 32
C5: convolutional layer, batch_size x 1 x 1 x 64, convolution size: 5 x 5 x 32 x 64
Dropout
F6: fully-connected layer, weight size: 64 x 16
Output layer, weight size: 16 x 11

Comment: you should crop the clock to get better results... There is no other way you can achieve a better accuracy with giving that as input to the network

Comment: I used a sliding window

Comment: what was the size of the sliding windows... what was the stride of sliding windows ?? did you scale the sliding window so that the clock fits the sliding window... did you check whether the clock digits fits the sliding window...